# X-Editable AJAX call not working after disabling / enabling

Tags: javascript, html, x-editable

I recently stumbled across a problem with enabling / disabling X-Editable forms which I have (after days of trying) not been able to solve yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've created a fiddle containing the core of my problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/11749/

- I have multiple labels which are editable;
- The input should be submitted to a server using ajax;

Up to here everything works perfect. But then there is also a button who is basically just disabling and enabling (right after disabling) the x-editable functionality.

If you click this button before you edit the labels - the AJAX call isn't made.

Things you might find suspicious:

- The selector: In my (simplified) example, the selector isn't actually needed. It's there because parts of our application are dynamically (re)loaded.
- Why am i trying to do this? I have multiple labels which should all be editable - but only one at I time. So if the focus changes, I disable all of them and enable the one who just got the focus. Well, at least I try to do that...

Thanks for any help!

Here's the HTML:

```
<button type="button" id='thebutton'>Don't click Me!</button>
<div style="margin: 150px" id='navi'>
<h4>
<a href="#" class='title'>awesome 1</a>
</h4>    
<h4>
<a href="#" class='title'>awesome 2</a>
</h4>    
<h4>
<a href="#" class='title'>awesome 3</a>
</h4>
</div>
<div id='output'>
...
</div>
```

And here's the JS:

```
$('#navi').editable({
selector:'.title',
  url: function(params) {
    $.ajax({    
      url: '/echo/js/?js=SUBMITTED!',
      complete: function(response) {
        $('#output').html(response.responseText);
      },
      error: function() {
        $('#output').html('Bummer: there was an error!');
      },
    });
  },
  send: 'always'
});

jQuery('body').on('click', '#thebutton', function () {
            $('.title').editable('toggleDisabled');
            $('.title').editable('toggleDisabled');
})
```

---

**Edited - Some additional information:**

We have a navigation (which is basically a "folder structure") which is created by the user. This means the user should be able to add additional navigation items and rename them if he wants. *The user is only allowed to rename the active item.* The content of each item gets dynamically loaded in the main panel.

[The Navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9ElC.png)

So when the user selects an item, the following script is run (which disables x-editable functionality on all links and reactivites it on the new active one:

```
        if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
                    // Load content to the main panel
                    DisplayOpRiskLeaf($(this).attr('id'));
                    // Change active navigation element
                    $('.oprisk-link').removeClass("active");
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                    $('.oprisk-leaves-panel').removeClass("active");
                    $(this).parents('.oprisk-leaves-panel').addClass("active");
                    // Change x-editable...
                    // disable all ($(this) is also getting disabled here)
                    $('.portfolio-title').editable('option', 'disabled', true);
                    // enable the active elemnt
                    $(this).editable('option', 'disabled', false);

                }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of double-toggling disabled? Could you explain what is your desired behaviour which is not happening?

Comment: I've added some additional information to the question.

Comment: In my definition of "toggle" doing it twice is the same as not doing. Of you try tro trigger something on the first toggle, why not call that directly? Doing it like this will probably never trigger the active-event, since the dom changed back before the selector is run

Comment: _In my definition of "toggle" doing it twice is the same as not doing._- I absolutly agree. But if you you have a look at the jsfiddle, this is not what's happining. Another example: I have 10 items, one of them is editable. Now i click on another one (which is currently not editable) and want it to get editable. Therefore i disable all 10 items (so i get the one which was editable before) and enable the new one.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot the mention the main point in the example above: The new editable item (the one i just clicked on) got disabled (alltough it already was disabled) and enabled again.

Comment: So, you just want to be able to enable and disable any editable field on request, right?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want, take a look at the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YuriJF/xBB5x/11783/)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts @Yuri. This is exactly what i want, but your example is not working aswell: The data does not get submitted after clicking the buttons. Otherwise "SUBMITTED" should appear on the bottom af the page (like it does when you edit without having clicked any buttons before)

Comment: P.S. If we remove the selector in your (or my) Fiddle it works as expected [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/11786/). But since i need the selector (everything is loaded "dynamically") this doesn't do it for me...